# OData query that uses .IncludeTotalCount() on a filtered (where clause) query

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

Say I have the following query on the Netflix OData Endpoint:

```
Titles.Where(x=>x.AverageRating > 3.0)
```

Is there a way to use `.IncludeTotalCount()` to get the count of titles that fit the where clause?  (Not the total count of items in the `Titles` resource.)

I looked at the code provided here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee474390.aspx

But it does not seem to work with a where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Vitek Karas' response and your comments, it looks like you need to cast the IQueryable you get back from the where clause to DataServiceQuery.

Answer (score 7):

I tried this and it works just fine:

```
DemoService ctx = new DemoService(new Uri("http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/"));
var query = (DataServiceQuery<Product>)ctx.Products.IncludeTotalCount().Where(p => p.Rating < 4);
QueryOperationResponse<Product> response = (QueryOperationResponse<Product>)query.Execute();
Console.WriteLine(response.TotalCount);
foreach (var i in response)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.Name + ", " + i.Rating.ToString());
}
```

What does it mean "it does not work" in your case?

Comment: When I try to run this I get this error: ***'System.Linq.IQueryable<Product>' does not contain a definition for 'Execute' and no extension method 'Execute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Product>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)***

Comment: This is the core of the problem that caused me to ask the question.  When you put a where clause on the query it returns an `IQueryable` instead of `DataServiceQuery`.

Comment: Just cast the IQueryable to DataServiceQuery - it is the right instance, just Where is declared as returning IQueryable.]